# Apache doesn’t start with “SSL Engine on” - Arch linux

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, manjaro

I'm trying to enable SSL on a virtual host...
TSL Section: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apache_HTTP_Server#TLS

I generate cert:

```
cd /etc/httpd/conf
sudo openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server.key                                                    1 ✘ 
sudo openssl req -new -sha256 -key server.key -out server.crt
```

Uncomment in '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf':

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf      <- this cause apache error
```

Apache (httpd) no longer starts...

As soon as I use:
`SSLEngine on`
Apache doesn't start...

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/user/www/saniday"
    ServerName saniday.test
    ServerAlias saniday.test
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/saniday.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/saniday.test-access_log" common

    <Directory "/home/user/www/saniday">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin mail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/user/www/saniday"
    ServerName saniday.test:443
    ServerAlias saniday.test:443
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/saniday.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/saniday.test-access_log" common

    SSLEngine on                  #  <- this cause apache error
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/conf/server.key"

    <Directory "/home/user/www/saniday">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

My controls...

```
$ apachectl configtest
> Syntax OK
```

Generate cert with:

```
sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/server.key -out /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/server.csr
```

It seems that as soon as I write "SSLEngine on" in the configuration file, Apache doesn't start.
Do I need to install any packages?

Error:

```
× httpd.service - Apache Web Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-10-28 16:41:26 CEST; 2s ago
   Duration: 30ms
    Process: 21651 ExecStart=/usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 21651 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 21ms

ott 28 16:41:26 Domenico-PC systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
ott 28 16:41:26 Domenico-PC systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ott 28 16:41:26 Domenico-PC systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```